# How do you make a label clickable and call a c# method

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

Is it possible to add an onClick event to an asp:label and let it call a c# method rather than js?
Something like:

```
<asp:Label
            ID="lblTest"
            runat="server"
            Text=""
            ToolTip="Amount of errors this person is processing"
            Style="cursor: help;"
            OnClick="lbl_Click"
            />
```

And on the server side:

```
protected void lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
lblTest.Text = "Clicked"
}
```

Comment: OnClick isn't a valid attribute of the element label apperantly :P

Comment: There is no server side onclick event for label

Comment: you can invoking server side event though javascript on label click

Comment: Why not use a button and style it as a label with CSS?

Comment: You can change the text through javascript

Comment: @ste-fu Yea that's exactly what I had in mind as an alternative, but I was curious if there was a way to do it with a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create linkedbutton and make it look like label using CSS like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="myclass" 
    OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">
MyButton
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in CSS

```
a.myclass{ color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
a.myclass:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

and then call it like

```
public void LinkButton1_Click()
{
    lblTest.Text = "Clicked"
}
```

Comment: Yep, exactly what I settled down to. Seems like the easiest way to do it.